# How to ge the data rows which is belonging to one date

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have table like.

```
ID | startdatetime
1  | 2013-08-30 22:30:00
2  | 2013-08-29 12:00:00
3  | 2013-08-29 13:30:00
4  | 2013-08-27 11:30:00
5  | 2013-08-27 13:30:00
6  | 2013-08-26 09:30:00
```

I want to get the the data which are belonging to a date (for example rows 2 and 3 are belonging to `2013-08-29` )

How could I write in Doctrine?

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

$items = $em->getRepository("UserBundle:Table")->findBy('startdatetime' => '*****'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1 - the quick and dirty one is to use the MySQL SUBSTRING to get the date out of the datetime:

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(dateTimeField,1,10) = '2013-08-29'
```

2 - Use [DoctrineExtensions](https://www.simukti.net/blog/2012/04/05/how-to-select-year-month-day-in-doctrine2/) and then you can select data like this:

```
$q->select('p')
  ->where('YEAR(startdatetime) = :year')
  ->andWhere('MONTH(startdatetime) = :month')
  ->andWhere('DAY(startdatetime) = :day');

$q->setParameter('year', $year)
  ->setParameter('month', $month)
  ->setParameter('day', $day);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

Add a `getDay()` function in your `Table` repository:

```
public function getDay($date)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');

    $q = $qb
        ->add('where',
        $qb->expr()->like('t.startdatetime', 
            $qb->expr()->literal($date.'%')))
        ->getQuery();

    return $q->getResult();
}
```

Then just call this function:

```
$items = $em->getRepository("UserBundle:Table")
    ->getDay('2013-08-29');
```